# How to release a project on GitHub on basis on commit ID?

Tags: git, github, release, commit, git-commit

I'm looking for a way to release my project at a commit I've made several days ago. I don't know whether is it possible or not, but would glad to see a solution for this.

I've gone through this [Creating Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases) an article by GitHub but didn't found there anything specifically mentioning about my requirement.

## Update:

My current project is 2 commit ahead of that commit which I want to make a release. I'm specifically looking for a solution for this since, it would help me to create version.

The old one I'll assign it as v1.0 and the new one will be v2.0 as the approach for both of them is different and then whenever I'll make any enhancement in any of those 2 versions then they'll continue their naming conventions as v1.1 and v2.1 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

OK, got the answer.

Just after the `Tag version` there is an option of selecting your `Commit ID`, we can select our commit ID from there and then its done.

Comment: Yeah, the way `git` makes "persistent versions" is tags. Commandline `git tag`. I guess the github GUI is just some frontend to that, which also provides an archived (zip/tarball) version of that commit's tree state.